# Is it possible to download to files while in a SSH interactive?

Tags: ssh, download

Here I am, poking around a remote server via SSH, and I want to find out about/read/edit/whatever a file. I don't like `vi` or other CMI stuff, I want to read it locally.

Is there any way I can download it without exiting my interactive SSH session?
(Even better, would there be any way to run local commands without exiting it?)

Comment: You mean directly in the same terminal as the existing SSH session?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **scp** like scp file **youruser@yourlocalmachine:** .

Or you can use the **-X** parameter, will allow you to use window programas for example gedit.

Comment: I didn't know about the -X parameter. Also I didn't think of setting up a SSH server on my own box, that's an unexpectedly amusing idea.